# Codeigniter Pagination start from different page and different active link for different employee while code is same

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, pagination

I have employee's attendance details, i want to show these details with pagination but the problem is that pagination start from different page number. for some user it start  from first page, while for others user it start for 2nd, 5th page. While pagination should start from first page for every users.
I don't know where is the problem. I am fresher. Please guide me.

**Controller :**

```
public function attendance($biometric_reg_number) {

    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->model('Attendance_model', 'attendances');
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $config = [
        'base_url'        => base_url("admin/attendance/attendance/{$biometric_reg_number}"),
        'per_page'        => 30,
        'total_rows'      => $this->attendances->filter_attenceby_admin_num_rows($biometric_reg_number),
        'full_tag_open'   => "<ul class='pagination'>",
        'full_tag_close'  => "</ul>",
        'first_link'      => "First",
        'first_tag_open'  => '<li>',
        'first_tag_close' => '</li>',
        'last_link'       => 'Last',
        'last_tag_open'   => '<li>',
        'last_tag_close'  => '</li>',
        'next_tag_open'   => '<li>',
        'next_tag_close'  => '</li>',
        'prev_tag_open'   => '<li>',
        'prev_tag_close'  => '</li>',
        'num_tag_open'    => '<li>',
        'num_tag_close'   => '</li>',
        'cur_tag_open'    => "<li class='active'><a>",
        'cur_tag_close'   => '</a></li>',
    ];
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $this->load->model('Attendance_model', 'attendances');
    $attendances = $this->attendances->find_attendance_detail($biometric_reg_number, $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(5));
    $this->load->view('admin/attendance', ['attendances' => $attendances]);
}
```

**Model :**

```
public function find_attendance_detail($biometric_reg_number, $limit, $offset) {
    $q = $this->db->select('*')
        ->from('basic_detail')
        ->join('employeedata', "employeedata.biometric_reg_number = basic_detail.biometric_reg_number")
        ->where('basic_detail.biometric_reg_number', $biometric_reg_number)
        ->limit($limit, $offset)
        ->order_by('employee_date', 'DESC')
        ->get();

    return $q->result();

}

public function filter_attenceby_admin_num_rows($biometric_reg_number) {
    $q = $this->db->select('*')
        ->from('basic_detail')
        ->join('employeedata', "employeedata.biometric_reg_number = basic_detail.biometric_reg_number")
        ->where('basic_detail.biometric_reg_number', $biometric_reg_number)
        //->order_by('employee_date','DESC')
        ->get();

    return $q->num_rows();
}
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KA5Mm.png)

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9oaW.png)
[image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NJkL.png)

Comment: It appears that your page number is $biometric_reg_number. For those screen shots you showed, you didn't display the url being used ( just the controller/ and all the rest of it ).

Comment: this is my first url when i display details ( /admin/attendance/attendance/48 )                                                         where 48 is biometric number And when i paginate then url is  (/admin/attendance/attendance/48/60). I am showing 30 per page.

Comment: And what page number does that start at with 48?

Comment: It starts from 2nd page. I mean active link is on 2nd while it should be start from first page.

Answer (score 0):

You're not setting the uri_segment in $config.

```
$config['uri_segment'] = 5
```

The number should be the page number, not the actual record offset.
You should set the page in a variable in case uri(5) isn't set.

```
$page = ($this->uri->segment(5)) ? ($this->uri->segment(5) - 1) : 0;
```

And call find_attendance_detail with $page.

```
$attendances = $this->attendances->find_attendance_detail($biometric_reg_number, $config['per_page'], ($page * 30));
```

Also you should use sql COUNT to get the total record count and you don't need the join.

SQL sort of like this.

```
select count(*) from basic_detail 
where basic_detail.biometric_reg_number = $biometric_reg_number;
```

(I don't use CI query builder so I don't know the exact command.)